# Find computed columns in SQL Server views

Tags: sql-server

A colleague asked me to help them to identify the views in a database that have one or more computed columns.  The database has hundreds of views so they're trying to find an automated way to accomplish this task.  I am not seeing the results in the database that I was expecting.  Here is an example:

```
--DROP TABLE dbo.Products

CREATE TABLE dbo.Products   
(  
    ProductID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL  
  , QtyAvailable smallint  
  , UnitPrice money   
);  

--DROP VIEW dbo.uvw_Products
CREATE VIEW dbo.uvw_Products
AS
    SELECT    ProductID
            , QtyAvailable
            , UnitPrice
            , (QtyAvailable * UnitPrice) AS InventoryValue
    FROM      dbo.Products;

-- Look at the view and find the computed column
SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(T.[object_id],DB_ID()) AS [Schema],   
        T.[name] AS [table_name], AC.[name] AS [column_name],   
        TY.[name] AS system_data_type, AC.[max_length],  
        AC.[precision], AC.[scale], AC.[is_nullable], AC.[is_ansi_padded], AC.[is_computed]
FROM sys.[views] AS T   
  INNER JOIN sys.[all_columns] AC ON T.[object_id] = AC.[object_id]  
 INNER JOIN sys.[types] TY ON AC.[system_type_id] = TY.[system_type_id] AND AC.[user_type_id] = TY.[user_type_id]  
WHERE T.[is_ms_shipped] = 0
AND T.[name] = 'uvw_Products'
ORDER BY T.[name], AC.[column_id]


-- Pulls up no results - no entries in sys.computed_columns
SELECT TOP 10 * 
FROM sys.computed_columns C
INNER JOIN sys.views V ON C.[object_id] = V.[object_id]
WHERE V.[name] = 'uvw_Products'
```

As you can see from this simple example, SQL Server does not seem to be storing the value in the is_computed column.

What am I missing?  How can we find the computed columns in views?

Comment: That is because InventoryValue is NOT a computed column. It is a derived column. Subtle but very important difference. A computed column is a calculation on a table. A view is just a stored query and the data cannot be persisted like it can with a computed column. What you are asking for is nearly impossible to get right. You would have to parse the view text for every view and hope you get it right.

Comment: By the way, you did a great job posting all the relevant details in your question. Something I wish more people would understand.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not ideal, I don't think a fool-proof solution exists for this problem, but depending on your naming conventions you could do a join to the tables sys view on column names so see which columns exist and don't exist in there.

for example:

```
SELECT v.*
FROM 
(
    SELECT  [Schema]        = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.[object_id], DB_ID())
          , [table_name]    = t.[name] 
          , [column_name]   = vc.[name]
    FROM sys.[views] t  
    JOIN sys.[all_columns] vc ON t.[object_id] = vc.[object_id]
) v
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT  [Schema]        = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.[object_id], DB_ID())
          , [table_name]    = t.[name] 
          , [column_name]   = vc.[name]
    FROM sys.[tables] t  
    JOIN sys.[all_columns] vc ON t.[object_id] = vc.[object_id]
) t
    ON t.[column_name] = v.[column_name]
WHERE t.[table_name] IS NULL
```

Returns:

```
Schema | table_name    | column_name
----------------------------------------
dbo    | uvw_Products  | InventoryValue
```

And if your views contain the source table in its name like 'uvw_Products' you could also use that in your join to avoid columns in other tables getting in the way.

Again its not ideal but a relatively simple solution to narrow the search